# Error installing anaconda in docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

I am quite new to docker. I am trying to make docker container to deploy web application (made by Django) to cloud.
However, when I try to build by following Dockerfile, I got the error

> Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
>   ResolvePackageNotFound:
>     -python 3.5.3 3

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# package install & update 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN apt-get -y install git vim curl wget
RUN apt-get -y install python-dev \
                       libmysqlclient-dev


FROM continuumio/anaconda3
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]

ADD env.yml /tmp/env.yml
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN [ "conda", "env", "create", "-f", "env.yml" ]


#ADD . /code/

RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate BAUES" ]

#RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "python manage.py migrate" ]

#RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "python manage.py runserver" ]
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Thank you.

Comment: There is probably no ready install for python 3.5.3.3 available within anaconda. The details are hidden in your env.yml which you did not show. Depending on the task, you might be less strict about the python you need (and specify in env.yml). 3.5.3.3 vs. 3.5 vs >= 3.5 and co.